# MySQL - find table in DB complexity

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, time-complexity

Simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

I would like to know what is the **complexity of finding the table**. Is it O(n)?

I am working with Wordpress multi-site. It creates additional 8 tables for each blog. Currently there are ~40k blogs so there are **more than 300k tables** already in a single DB.

I am asking this because I would like to understand how to behave at this point, I would like to avoid future bottlenecks.

Thanks!

Comment: look at [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html)

Comment: What is the complexity of finding a table in a DB? In other words, how MySQL selects the relevant table before it selects its content?

Comment: I think the question has a (sligthly) better chance on serverfault.com to get "real world" answers.

Answer (score 1):

Usually having large number of tables like 100-200 doesn't effect your database, but 300k tables is insane.

Think of tables like your folders, and rows as file. Now your operating system has indexed all the files in different folders, which makes searching for a file lot easier. But an operating system cant just index every file on your system, it has a memory limit.

**Similarly in MYSQL** every table has an index, and all these indexes are stored in RAM. Now if you have too many indexes, then your RAM wont be able to hold all that data. So in order to avoid crashing the server, it saves the index to the hard drive. But hard drives are much slower than RAM's and will take a lot longer to find the indexes.

To be honest this kind of database cannot be handled by a normal VPS server. To get most out of your system you will have to rent a server with very high RAM. Try using a separate managed database system like AWS RDS with autoscalling which will leave the tweeking and autoscaling of database to the experts. If RDS is not possible, try increasing **key_buffer_size** in your my.cnf to the maximum you can have. That way more data will be stored on your RAM and less on your Hard drive.

Good luck, and do share your findings in the comments as its pretty interesting to see how you overcome it :)